# Checking the bash process in Terminal 1 is the parent process of a child process, FROM terminal 2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, process

I have 2 terminals open. In terminal 1 I have `bash` running, then I run `xlogo`; `xlogo` is the child of course. If I type `ps T o user,pid,tty,args,ppid` it gives me:

```
USER         PID TT       COMMAND                        PPID
shahzeb     2526 pts/3    bash                           2248
shahzeb     2762 pts/3    xlogo                          2526
shahzeb     3152 pts/3    ps T o user,pid,tty,args,pp    2526
```

but if I do that in terminal 2 it does not list `xlogo` only bash with different pid.

My question is how can I type something in Terminal 2 and verify that the `bash` process in Terminal 1 is the parent process of the `xlogo` process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ps` command, by default prints information about all processes with the same effective user id as the current user, and associated with the same terminal as the invoker.  That's why you don't see `xlogo` or its parent `bash` process when running it from terminal 2.

If you want to see things outside the scope of the default behavior, then you'll need to pass additional arguments to `ps` to change that behavior.  One option is to use the `-A` option, for example: `ps -A T o user,pid,tty,args,ppid`.

Comment: I think the T is not needed. The OP can try with his data ps -t pts/3 o user,pid,tty,args,ppid

Comment: I didn't parse all the option the OP used, I just appended the `-A` to whatever the OP had.